# Is correlation a percentage?

Tags: correlation, terminology, pearson-r, percentage

The Pearson correlation coefficient ranges from -1 to 1. Oftentimes, people take this number, multiply it by 100 and call it

> -17.3% correlation

or

> 63% correlation

I was once dinged by reviewers for this, in a STEM journal. Is this really a mistake?

---

**Examples of real-world usage:**

Book: [Spurious Correlations](https://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations):

[image]

Textbook: [Clear-Sighted Statistics: Module 18: Linear Correlation and Regression](https://academicworks.cuny.edu/qb_oers/136/):

[image]

Comment: It's potentially confusing, because $\rho$ is not a fraction of any quantity.  Its *square* can be interpreted as a percentage, so technically one ought to write "$-17.3\sqrt{\%}$" correlation!

Comment: @Stephan I haven't researched this topic well enough to answer.  I suspect there may be communities in which expressing $\rho$ as a percent is allowed.  When the "%" sign is understood *purely* as meaning "divide the preceding number by 100," there might not be a problem. That's why I left my remark as a comment. Although I am unable, after several pages of Googling, to find even a single example of expressing $\rho$ in percent, the good people on Quora believe (without any citations) [this to be just  fine](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-correlation-coefficient-be-written-as-a-percentage).

Comment: I examined many of the first 100 hits in a Google search on "pearson correlation coefficient percent*", focusing on sites I felt would be most likely to reflect different communities or be purveyors of misconceptions.  Even the worst (with kindergarten-like graphics and cutesy language) insist $\rho$ lies between $-1.0$ and $1.0.$  *None* of them express it as a percent.  This includes dummies.com, some government sites, *etc.*

Comment: Naively thinking, it is actually a ratio, so calling it percentage may be tempting. But I agree with @whuber's comments, it is not a percentage of any kind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s wrong, and if a reviewer wants to tell you to change it, you have no argument. I would not, however, consider that to be more than a typo (minor revision), even if I said it should be changed.

I see an argument that it’s just a slang that perhaps has no place in formal writing like a scientific article but is fine for casual discussions. However, squaring the correlation has an interpretation as a proportion or percentage (it’s $R^2$ in a regression involving your two variables), so I think I do not like such a slang. If you mentioned having a correlation of $81\%$, that could correspond to $r=0.81$, $r=0.9$, or $r=-0.9$.

Comment: *"a correlation of 81% could correspond to $r = 0.9$ "*. But $r^2$ is not "a correlation". I don't think there is an ambiguity here.

Comment: @MWB Someone could be being loose with their terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Informally, you can do whatever works for you/your group. I can see a lot of reason why it can be easy to visualize a set of positive correlations as proportions towards two ideal states (0 and 1).

However, formally, I think this is wrong on many conceptual levels. Most important: correlations measures are (usually) not additive. It means that the difference in information between $r = .5$ and $r = -0.5$ is not the same as the difference between $r = 1$ and $r = 0$ even if the metric difference is the same. And this holds whatever two couples of points in the scale you take, roughly.

Personally, I came to the idea that if you are not at the market, adding $%$ to numbers is always a bad choice because it is misleading.

Comment: "Most important: correlations measures are (usually) not additive" - I would think it would be most important whether or not correlation actually represents a fraction. If it does, then it would be correct to use percentage even if it isn't additive, and if it doesn't, then using percentage wouldn't be correct even if it's additive.

Comment: "the difference in information between r=.5 and r=−0.5 is not the same as the difference between r=1 and r=0" - is the difference in information between -50% and 50% equal to the difference between 0% and 100%? I might say no, but it depends how you interpret it. Negative percentages are perhaps a bit questionable in any case (unless it's a delta), but this can be trivially solved by interpreting the negative sign differently.